# How does one toggle auto update in Isabelle with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, isabelle, theorem-proving

I wanted to stop isabelle from doing the proof steps as I write since its impossible to remember complicated equations as I try to tell it with rule_tac what the term should be while it dissapears.

Is there a keyboard short cut with isabelle for auto update?

Answer (score 2):

The action is called "Update state output" in the keybinding section (Plugin menu > Plugin, Global option tab, jEdit > Keybindings in the bar on the left) and is by default bound to S-ENTER.

So untik the "Auto update" and press shift-enter to update the state panel.